# How do I run my own Stellar blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain

Let me first say that this is a very trivial question and might even seem idiotic. I'm new to blockchain technology, and I'd like to get started by building my own network (to experiment). So far according to my research, it seems like Hyperledger Fabric and Stellar are good choices, but I was not able to find the SDK for Stellar's out of the box. That is, it seems like I cannot build **my own** network with Stellar. Is this correct? If so, what are the "key words" I should be look for to find blockchain frameworks that I can use to build **my own** network?

---

EDIT: Let me elaborate a bit more. According to Stellar's official developer's guide:

> In order to create an account, you need to run a `CreateAccount` operation with your new account ID. Due to Stellar’s account minimums, you’ll need to transfer the minimum account balance from another account with the create account operation. As of this writing, minimum balance is 1 XLM (2 x 0.5 Base Reserve), and is subject to change.

This makes it seem like I cannot create my own network and must therefore rely on the official Stellar network for all of my applications. Is this correct?

Comment: To potential voters. OP is asking for keywords to narrow down the search, not answers to the search. Don't close just because it seems to fit in that category. Who are you helping here?

Comment: Well, the title is very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use the [stellar-core project](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core) to run your own.

Quoting the install instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core.git
cd stellar-core
git submodule init
git submodule update
Type ./autogen.sh.
Type ./configure (If configure complains about compiler versions, try CXX=clang-5.0 ./configure or CXX=g++-5 ./configure or similar, depending on your compiler.)
Type make or make -j (for aggressive parallel build)
Type make check to run tests.
Type make install to install.
```

Comment: In the end you can even use the pre-compiled `stellar-core` binary, the network is defined with the `network passphrase` and servers you declare in your configuration.